# execute code inside subscribe on condition

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have observable data in my angular2 app. The data has 2 properties

```
 {isFetching: false, user: {userID: 1, firstName: "john", lastName: "public"} }.
```

When the data is getting retrieved from server isFetching flag is true and user object is null. In one of my component I need to get some other data by userID that is on the observable object.Initially when the observable is subscribed user object is null. In my code I am having to check if the user is null before performing some other action. Below code works, but I think there has to be better way than having if condition inside subscribe block.

```
this.store.select<UserProfileState>('user')
        .subscribe(user => {
            if (!user.isFetching) {
              this.store.dispatch(this.informationPanelActions.loadInformationPanel(user.user.clientID, user.user.userID));
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're working with an Observable, you can use filter :

```
this.store.select<UserProfileState>('user')
    .filter(user => !user.isFetching)
    .subscribe(user => {
        this.store.dispatch(this.informationPanelActions.loadInformationPanel(user.user.clientID, user.user.userID));
    });
```